# How can I return the last date by the last 12 months (SQL Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I don't know how to return the last date of the month. Currently I have only this SQL statement which returns the last 12 months:

```
SELECT *
FROM KENNZAHL
WHERE ID=325 And Datum>=DateAdd("m",-12,Date())
ORDER BY Datum DESC;
```

It is good, but I need only the last date of these 12 months. Do anyone has an idea?

p.s.: I'm using ms access 2010.

for example:

Result:

```
ID  | Datum
325 | 2017-01-31
325 | 2016-12-31
325 | 2016-11-30
325 | 2016-10-31
325 | 2016-09-31
.....
```

Comment: You only want the date? That would be `MAX(Datum)`. Or do you want the complete record for `MAX(Datum)`? Or `MAX(Datum)` per month? Or something else still?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I edited my post

Comment: There is no 2016-09-31.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum date per month:

```
SELECT MAX(Datum)
FROM KENNZAHL
WHERE ID=325 And Datum>=DateAdd("m",-12,Date())
GROUP BY YEAR(Datum), MONTH(Datum)
ORDER BY YEAR(Datum) DESC, MONTH(Datum) DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is now that the result isn't correct sorted. it starts with 2016-12-30 and ended with 2017-01-31... The correct way would be 2017-01-31, 2016-12-30, 2016-11-30 and so on.

Comment: Okay, then group and order by year, too. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

If there´s only one entry with that last date you could use

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM KENNZAHL
WHERE ID=325
ORDER BY Datum DESC;
```